# access elements of a list from a modified list

Tags: python

Say I have a list:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

And I've produced another list from the one above, on the basis of some elements meeting a condition, lets say having a value equal to three:

```
[[0, 3], [3, 0]]
```

But now I want to access some elements from the bigger list, on the basis of some modification to my second list, lets say subtracting two from only those values equal to three in the second list. So I want to access those values in the first list taking the values [0,1] and [1,0] for the case of my second list here.
How do I proceed?

Comment: I don't get it, could you please be more specific?

Comment: Please can you write an example of what you want

Comment: Okay I'll edit and add some more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> lis = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
>>> lis1 = [[0, 3], [3, 0]]
#generate lis2 from lis1 based on a condition
>>> lis2 = [[y if y!=3 else y-2 for y in x] for x in lis1]
>>> lis2
[[0, 1], [1, 0]]
#use sets to improve time complexity
>>> s = set(tuple(x) for x in lis2)

#Now use set intersection  or a list comprehension to get the
#common elements between lis2 and lis1. Note that set only contains unique items 
#so prefer list comprehension if you want all elements from lis that are in lis2 
#as well.

>>> [x for x in lis if tuple(x) in s]
[[0, 1], [1, 0]]
>>> s.intersection(map(tuple,lis))
{(0, 1), (1, 0)}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! However this solution when I run it is returning every entry in the first list, that is not equal to 3, rather than every entry that is 3-1. I must have some complications elsewhere in my code with the lists